# IncompleteAnnotationException: dagger.Provides missing element type

Tags: java, gson, kotlin, dagger

When I add the following code an error comes:

```
@Singleton @Provides fun provideGson() : Gson {
    return Gson()
}
```

I really don't know why.

Comment: what is the issue you got

Comment: No-repro for me, which version of dagger are you using?

Comment: dagger2.0 when i add up code ,The error is  IncompleteAnnotationException: dagger.Provides missing element type

Comment: The detail is when i create a android app use kotlin in android studio2.3.2, ,even add dagger ,it ok,but when i add the code "@provides... ",the error comes ,i find to solve it,but no more error detail,

Answer (score 9):

after updating Dagger to 2.12 (from 2.8) everything worked fine

Comment: daggerVersion = '2.28.1'

Answer (score 4):

I have faced exactly same issue in our project. In my case it was caused by change in Dagger2 API: Dagger2 developers [have removed](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/ec44324f806be46b9298882105a7c7d1ae991f7f) the `type` parameter from annotation `@Provides`.

I have accidentally used the new, incompatible version of annotation dependency (without `type` field in annotation) with old version of Dagger2 compiler. It seems, that unlike some other types of binary incompatibilities, which cause various runtime `Error`s, linkage with incompatible annotation may result in `IncompleteAnnotationException` during introspection.

Updating dagger2 compiler to the same version as annotation has fixed the issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I am using Dagger 2 with Kotlin (kapt) and can't figure out which two versions to match. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, finally got it to build: after updating Dagger to 2.12 (from 2.8) everything worked fine. Thank you, I would've wasted a lot more time figuring this out without your hint.

Comment: I fixed it updating to 2.12 too!